# UWP: Graph API ProfilePhoto

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, microsoft-graph-api

I am creating a uwp application that uses the Microsoft Graph API. I want the user to be able to see in PersonPicture the photo he uses in his account after logging in.How can I do this?
My code:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private async Task<BitmapImage> GetProfilePhotoAsync(Models.Models.OutlookUser authResult)
    {
        var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        try
        {
            var requestUserPhoto = authResult.GraphServiceClient.Me.Photo.Content.Request();

            using (var resultsUserPhoto = await requestUserPhoto.GetAsync())
            {
                using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    await resultsUserPhoto.CopyToAsync(memStream);
                    memStream.Position = 0;

                    bitmap.SetSource(memStream.AsRandomAccessStream());
                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here are few samples for fetching the profile photo of a signed-in in user with the helper's code

[image]

Reference document: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnetcore-connect-sample#helpers

Hope this helps.